# defining the variables of javascript inside the class scope

Tags: javascript

guys i know it is dummy question but i tried alot and never reached .. i want to define the variables of Javascript file inside the scope of the class not to be overridden by any outside source .. here is my code

```js
var pageSize = 5;
 var startIndex = 0;
 var endIndex = startIndex + pageSize;
 var page = 1;
 var textField;
 var check = 0;
// i want all of the above variables to be defined inside the scope of the class not outside 

function bindContext(fn, context) {
 return function() {
  fn.apply(context, arguments);
 }
}

function GridLibraryDep(data) {
 this.data = data;
 this.columns = $.map(this.data[0], function(item, key) {
  return key;
 });
 document.getElementById("from").innerHTML = 1;
 document.getElementById("to").innerHTML = pageSize;
 document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = data.length;
 $("#first").click(bindContext(this.first, this));
 $("#last").click(bindContext(this.last, this));

}


GridLibraryDep.prototype = {
  
 first : function() {
  var size = this.data.length;
  page = 1;
  // document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML = page;
  endIndex = page * pageSize;
  startIndex = endIndex - pageSize;
  this.deleteTable();
  document.getElementById("from").innerHTML = 1;
  document.getElementById("to").innerHTML = endIndex;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = size;
  this.display();
 },

 last : function() {
  var size = this.data.length;
  endIndex = size;
  startIndex = Math.floor(size / pageSize) * pageSize;
  page = Math.ceil(size / pageSize);
  this.deleteTable();
  // document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML = page;
  document.getElementById("from").innerHTML = startIndex + 1;
  document.getElementById("to").innerHTML = endIndex;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = size;
  this.display();
 }};
```

Comment: Should those variables be different/independent for each instance of `GridLibraryDep` or do you want that each instance share those variables?

Comment: i want each instance to share these variables

Comment: What exactly is your question? Just how to make "private" variables within `GridLibraryDep`?

Comment: nope .. i want the satrtIndex and all of these variables to be declared inside the scope of GridLibraryDep not outside  ... btw these variables are shared among instances

Comment: I delete my answer because it is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score -1):

This is a common way to create a prototype Class - https://jsfiddle.net/aaronfranco/fysbbdp7/10/

```
var MyClass = MyClass || {};

(function () {
    "use strict";

    //============================================================
    // Constructor - MUST BE AT TOP OF FILE
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    MyClass = function () {
        this.created = true;
    };

    //============================================================
    // Member Functions & Variables
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    MyClass.prototype = {
        pageSize:5,
        startIndex:0,
        endIndex:0,
        page:1,
        textField:null,
        check:0,
        init: function(){
            this.endIndex = this.startIndex + this.pageSize;
        },
        first : function() {
          // function here
          console.log(this.endIndex);
        },

        last : function() {
          // function here
          //alert(this.pageIndex);
          console.log(this.pageSize)
        },
        iterater: function(int) {
          console.log(this.pageSize);
          this.pageSize += int;
        }
    }
})();
```

Here is the example usage available in the JSFiddle link above:

```
var newClass = new MyClass();
newClass.init();
newClass.first();

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    newClass.iterater(i);
  newClass.last();
}
```

Using this "namespaced" technique, you can instantiate this class using

```
var newClass = new MyClass();
newClass.init();
```

You could then create protected variables in the class by making them private. There is a good article about some potential ways to create protected variables here.

http://philipwalton.com/articles/implementing-private-and-protected-members-in-javascript/

Comment: it gives me pageSize is not defined

Comment: The `var MyClass = MyClass || {};` does not make much sense, because it is equal to `var MyClass = {};`. Your `(function () { ... })` is not called because you miss a `()` that invokes that function. If you add the `()` to invoke the function then the `var MyClass = {};`  does not make sense because you immediately overwrite the `MyClass`. In addition `endIndex:this.startIndex + this.pageSize,` does not make sense, because `this` is `window` in the given example.

Comment: You can read more about Namespacing here: https://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/. I agree that you need to move the "endIndex" assignment to an initialization function... I don't have time to write every line of code for you... This is a model for writing a class which is quite easy to debug.

Comment: @yomnaesam where are you calling pageSize that you are getting undefined? In a function, you would have to call this.pageSize

Comment: `this.pageSize` is undefined here: `endIndex : this.startIndex + this.pageSize,` because `this` is  `window` at the time `this.startIndex + this.pageSize` is evaluated.

Comment: "i want to define the variables of Javascript file inside the scope of the class not to be overridden by any outside source .." is in the question

Comment: still gives me all variables is not difined

Comment: Then @yomnaesam has to clarify this. Because as response to the I and _Matthew Herbst_  asked in the comments and the OP said two times that the `variables are shared among instances`.

Comment: i mean that pageSize and startIndex and endIndex are shared among functions

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fysbbdp7/1/ -  This fiddle shows that the variables are shared among functions.